# cannot install function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FormatExtractNumber]
    (@RawValue sql_variant)
RETURNS nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @FormatExtractNumber nvarchar(50)
    
    IF (SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@RawValue,'scale') = 0 or @RawValue > 100000000000000000000000000000)
    BEGIN
        SET @FormatExtractNumber = CONVERT(nvarchar(50),@RawValue) 
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Raw_dec dec(38,7)

        SET @FormatExtractNumber = CONVERT(nvarchar(50), @Raw_dec)
        SET @FormatExtractNumber = CASE WHEN @Raw_dec = 0 THEN N'0' ELSE CASE WHEN  CHARINDEX('.',@FormatExtractNumber) > 0 THEN TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM @FormatExtractNumber) ELSE @FormatExtractNumber END END
    END

    IF CHARINDEX(N'.',REVERSE(@FormatExtractNumber)) = 1
    BEGIN
        SET @FormatExtractNumber = REPLACE(@FormatExtractNumber, '.', '')
    END

    RETURN @FormatExtractNumber
END
```

I am getting the following error and I don't know why:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure FormatExtractNumber, Line 72 [Batch Start Line 9]
> Incorrect syntax near '0'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure FormatExtractNumber, Line 80 [Batch Start Line 9]
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure FormatExtractNumber, Line 83 [Batch Start Line 9]
> Incorrect syntax near 'END'

I have isolated the problem to the following line as, when I comment this part, I can get the function installed:

```
SET @FormatExtractNumber = CASE WHEN @Raw_dec = 0 THEN N'0' ELSE CASE WHEN  CHARINDEX('.',@FormatExtractNumber) > 0 THEN TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM @FormatExtractNumber) ELSE @FormatExtractNumber END END
```

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2022?

Comment: You'd be  better off, depending on how you are using this function, to create it as an inlibe table-valued function.

Answer (score 1):

compatibility level for the database had to be changed to SQL 2022. My partner had made changes to his db after he upgraded SQL Server there. He then ran the script there with no issues. I then upgraded SQL server from 2019 to 2022 here but had not changed compatibility level on the DB yet here.